# Magento 2: Getting dynamic url of image from media browser in js

Tags: magento-2.1, media-images, gallery, dynamic

So I have been building an extension to allow me to insert images into the textarea block of blocks and pages with custom styles. I call the MediabrowserUtility and am able to get a long funky url into a hidden input box, but this url doesn't work on the frontend and seems like I need a dynamic url in the form of `{{media url="wysiwyg/banner_image"}}`

Here is my js code:

```
/* my_js.phtml */
<?php
    $sourceUrl = $block->getUrl('cms/wysiwyg_images/index',
    ['target_element_id' => 'tce-image-chooser', 'type' => 'file']);
    $mediafn = 'MediabrowserUtility.openDialog(\'' . $sourceUrl . '\', 0, 0, \'MediaBrowser\', {});';
?>
<script>
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
    let openGallery = () => { <?= $mediafn ?> };

    let listener = null;

    $('#insert_image').click(evt => {
        clearInterval(listener);

        let image_selector = $('#tce-image-chooser')[0];
        let initVal = image_selector.value = 'tce-empty';

        openGallery();
        listener = setInterval(() => {
            if(image_selector.value !== initVal) {
                let url = image_selector.value;
                /* Do something with url */
            }
        }, 250);
    });
});
</script>
```

So currently the url I get is of the form: `https://domain.com/admin/cms/wysiwyg/directive/___directive/e3ttZWRpYSB1cmw9Ind5c2l3eWcvS2FmZmViX25uZXIucG5nIn19/key/a9b2feeed684ea00c0f02365f97a01627a14e7c2a6fa603a76e48b616a2e9bfa/` but I need it to be a dynamic url such as `{{media url="wysiwyg/banner_image"}}`

Any help or ideas will greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So after searching with slightly different keywords I found a solution from what someone mentioned.

Here is the code to go from the long url to the dynamic url:

```
    function urlToMageCode(url) {
        var parts = url.split('/');
        var key = parts.indexOf('___directive');
        if (key < 0) return false;
        let clean = parts[key+1].replace(/(%.*)$/, '');
        return atob(clean);
    }
```